# How to add angular js html5mode under controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new in Angular js.I try to make html5 mode true in one of my controller .In my angular js app there is 3 controller but i need to html5 mode true in one of them not in all controller. I am using

```
App.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);     
});
```

But this config effect all of my controller.I need to add html5mode true under one of my controller.I don't know is it possible or not .

Comment: its not possible, why do you want to do it for a controller btw?

Comment: In my site only 3 page used angular js controller .When i used config html5mode true the it just change the url not able load other page

Comment: that would mean that the route change configuration is wrong, rather than fixing html5mode, i think you should try to fix the routing part.

Comment: @Himanshu: Would you mind accepting the answer if it succeeds in answering your question ?

Answer (score 2):

Providers are only available when instantiating an Angular module. You can only use providers for a module before it is instantiated inside a config block. So you can configure `$locationProvider` once per module and not at the controller level.